# Sum values if any cell in corresponding row matches text

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following Google Sheets data:

```
Name1   Name2   Name3    Value
A       B       C        20
B       A       C        30
C       D       F        40
```

What I'm trying to do is see if a specific name appears in any of the three name columns. If it does, then sum all the values in the "Value" column for all matching rows.

For example, I want to sum all of the values for name "A". That name only appears on the first two rows, so it should do `20`+`30` to give me `50`. If I change the searched name to "C", that appears in all three rows so it should sum all of the numbers: `20`+`30`+`40`. The algorithm needs to adjust and search appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=DSum  will work

With the example you give use

```
=dsum(A1:D4,D1,{A1;"A"})+dsum(A1:D4,D1,{B1;"A"})+dsum(A1:D4,D1,{C1;"A"})
```

You can swap the "A" for a Cell reference

see https://drive.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0As3tAuweYU9QdEVHdTFHNzloSTY4LVYxdW9LdHRHbEE&mode=public#